# SQL RIGHT function equivalent in Entity framework Core

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working with a Net Core project, using entity framework, mysql database and pomelo framework. I need to perform this query, in order to compare the last X characters of a property in my model, against a pattern:

```
_context.Cars
.Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.CarName.ToString().Right(5), pattern))
.ToList();
```

I want to know if there is any SQL RIGHT function equivalent in Entity framework Core.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `Where(c => c.CarName.EndsWidth(pattern))` works? If it does not, what is the error message you get?

Comment: I need to compare the last X characters with the pattern. Example: CarName = "99114". If X = 3 and pattern = "%11%", then the item should be included in the results. But, if CarName="911", X = 1 and pattern = "%11%", the item should be excluded from the results. Using EndsWith would consider "911" as a valid result

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update (EF Core 5.0+):**

EF Core 5.0 introduces `IsBuiltIn` property on `DbFunctionAttribute` and `IsBuiltIn(bool)` fluent API, so providing translation is no more  necessary. The minimal mapping is the same as in EF Core 2.x, just

```cs
[DbFunction("RIGHT", "")]
```

is replaced with

```cs
[DbFunction("RIGHT", IsBuiltIn = true, IsNullable = true)]
```

EF Core 5 also allows [Configuring nullability of user-defined function based on its arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping#configuring-nullability-of-user-defined-function-based-on-its-arguments), but it can only be done fluently, so you might consider using explicit mapping rather than generic code. e.g.

```cs
public static class MyDbFunctions
{
    public static string Right(this string s, int length)
        => throw new InvalidOperationException();

    public static void Register(ModelBuilder modelBuider)
    {
        var fb = modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => Right(default, default))
            .HasName("RIGHT").IsBuiltIn(true).IsNullable(true);
        fb.HasParameter("s").PropagatesNullability(true);
    }
}
```

---

**Update (EF Core 3.0+):**

Starting with Ef Core 3.0, empty string schema is treated the same as `null`, i.e. prepends the default schema to to function name. This way, in case if you want to add built-in function, you have to provide "translation" (weird decision).

So you need to add

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions;
```

and modify the code as follows

```
modelBuider.HasDbFunction(dbFunc).HasTranslation(args =>
    SqlFunctionExpression.Create(dbFunc.Name, args, dbFunc.ReturnType, null));
```

---

**Original:**

Since currently there is neither CLR `string` nor `EF.Functions` method called `Right`, the answer is that EF Core currently does not provide equivalent of SQL `RIGHT` function.

Fortunately EF Core allows you to add it using the EF Core 2.0 introduced [Database scalar function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping).

For instance, add the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static class MyDbFunctions
    {
        [DbFunction("RIGHT", "")]
        public static string Right(this string source, int length)
        {
            if (length < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(length));
            if (source == null) return null;
            if (length >= source.Length) return source;
            return source.Substring(source.Length - length, length);
        }

        public static void Register(ModelBuilder modelBuider)
        {
            foreach (var dbFunc in typeof(MyDbFunctions).GetMethods().Where(m => Attribute.IsDefined(m, typeof(DbFunctionAttribute))))
                modelBuider.HasDbFunction(dbFunc);
        }
    }
}
```

(Later on you can add more functions like this if needed).

Then add call to `Register` from your context `OnModelCreating` override:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...
    MyDbFunctions.Register(modelBuilder);
    // ...
}
```

And you are done. Now you should be able to use the desired:

```
_context.Cars
.Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.CarName.ToString().Right(5), pattern))
.ToList();
```

Comment: This is definetly the right answer. I tested it and worked as expected. Thank you!!!

Comment: This gives me the following error:

Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.RIGHT", or the name is ambiguous.

I use the DbFunction the same way as in  your code example. DB - SQL Server.

Comment: @VladyslavKolodka Yeah, unfortunately they changed the meaning of `""` schema argument in 3.0 and it's no more treated as "no schema". Now one have to provide "translation". I will update the solution when have some time, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @IvanStoev fixed with this code:             modelBuilder
                .HasDbFunction(typeof(CustomDbFunctions).GetMethod(nameof(Right))!)
                .HasSchema(null)
                .HasTranslation(args => SqlFunctionExpression.Create("RIGHT", args, typeof(string), null));

Comment: @VladyslavKolodka Something like that.  Looks like `HasSchema(null)` is not needed, just `HasTranslation`.

Comment: This works, but the method "SqlFunctionExpression.Create(...)" is now being flagged with a warning as obsolete (I'm using EF Core 5). Substituting "new SqlFunctionExpression(...)" removes the warning. It has an extra required "argumentsPropagateNullability" argument, between "nullable" and "type", that takes IEnumerable<Boolean>.

Comment: @mcb2k3 Indeed, thanks for reminding me. There is also an easier way (similar to 2.x) w/o dealing with expressions (for simple scenarios like this). Answer updated.

Comment: @IvanStoev Can you please help me with a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69968162/replace-the-sql-query-with-the-linq-query  I am kind stuck as it comparison with date

Answer (score -1):

Use the following:

```
_context.Cars.Where(w => DbFunctions.Right(w.CarName,5)==pattern).ToList();
```