# Replace the SQL query with the LINQ query

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, select, azure-sql-database

I have the `SQL` query which checks today's day to be checked against the field in the table that stores 3 letter char like below

[image]

If today is Tuesday I need to return the record. I have the SQL query like

```
  SELECT TOP 1 [EndTime],[StartTime],[OrderDay]
         FROM[dbo].[Settings]
         where SUBSTRING(DATENAME(weekday, getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'), 0, 4) = OrderDay
```

Since the table is in the Azure SQL and my application run ins Eastern Time Zone I am doing like `SUBSTRING(DATENAME(weekday, getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'), 0, 4)` now I am using the EF core so I want to change the above query to the LINQ query like below

```
  settings_data = from s in _context.Settings
                  where SUBSTRING(DATENAME(weekday, getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'), 0, 4) = s.OrderDay
                  select s;
```

It says `SUBSTRING()` does not exist in the current context. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK Sure Thanks !I just wanted to show the value in the DB how it looks

Comment: Just show as tabular data, and for the definition show the DDL.

Comment: @DaleK Sure! Can you please help me with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in LinQ as you can't use integrated functions in select or where.

You have to do something like:

```
string myCondition = DateTime.UtcNow.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0,3);

  settings_data = from s in _context.Settings
                  where  s.OrderDay = myCondition 
                  select s;
```

You can use DateTime.Now or DateTime.UtcNow for UTC real time. `DayOfWeek` will get you the name of the day, and then for `Substring`: 0 is the start and 3 is the lenght.

**Update:**

To get `Eastern Standard Time` you can use:

```
var timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime easternTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);
```

and then:

```
string myCondition = easternTime.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0,3);
```

Test it:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/YFwnZo

Comment: Thank you !!! Is there a way to make the field `s.OrderDay` to uppercase in the where clause

Comment: @user4912134 if you really don't care about the uppercase you can use StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase or you can use Equals and try to get that. In my knowledge is better (if you can) make a view or a store procedure into the database and get the data as you need it and then use the linQ over the view or store procedure. Because you can't use ToUpper neither :S 
If this answer helps you please dont forget to upvote or mark it as answer, or if you need more help ask me here and I will glad to answer you :)

Comment: Thank you !! I am running in to another issue which is not associated with it, but can you please tell me if you can help me with it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69969014/cannot-access-the-field-value-from-the-linq-query-ef-core

Comment: @user4912134 no problem. Sorry Ive to sleep very late at night yesterday. Let me see if I know, what is about it